# A way to hold multiple views together in XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So, I know about LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.

Let's say I have a TextView and ImageView. I want to make both invisible. Sure, I could make both invisible separately. Logically though, both go hand in hand, so I would prefer to wrap them up in something, and make that invisible or visible.

I don't want to clutter the XML file with LinearLayout/RelativeLayout if I don't need to. Is there a simpler tool to hold both of them together?

Comment: FrameLayout.. positions views on top of views..so use it and set the old view invisible makes sense?

Comment: I had the same question a while back. Kind of how you would place different HTML elements in a DIV tag that does nothing but grouping them, right? There seems to be no such concept in Android (happy to learn that I'm wrong), pretty sure you rather don't add a new layout because that would increase rendering complexity.

Comment: @jangroth yep, that is exactly what I'm wondering.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of anything better I ended up using butterknife's ability (see [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)) to inject multiple views:

```
@InjectViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews
```

...and a trivial method to toggle the view state of these elements.

I think that's as good as it gets (and it's really only eye candy around *not grouping* the elements together).

So the answer to your question seems to be: No, there is no such thing.